# Hilfe ich spreche deutsch

Tags: discussion

Gibt es auch eine Möglichkeit  Ubuntu Fragen auch in deutscher Sprache zu betreiben ?

Verstehe den Sinn von " This question body does....." leider nicht  sorry

### Translation:

> Is it possible to use AskUbuntu in German?
>
> Unfortunately I don't understand "This question body does....."

Comment: AskUbuntu gibt es nur auf Englisch. Für ein deutschsprchiges Forum schau dir auf [ubuntuusers.de](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/).

Comment: @FlorianDiesch: that's not a comment!  That's an answer...  ;-)
Klaus, Nur English, aber ich verstehe auch Deutsch.  Schreiben ist zu schwierig!

Answer (score 4):

No, sorry. The policy across the Stack Exchange network is that all questions are in English except for those cases where a site is specifically in another language (e.g. [Portuguese SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [French](https://french.stackexchange.com/) or [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/). Any site that is not explicitly language-specific is implicitly specific to English.

However, you can use a service like [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com) to translate your posts. It is usually a horrible translation but might be enough for people to understand your question. Other users will then edit it to fix it and improve the translation.

---

Hier ist eine schreckliche Übersetzung meiner Antwort auf den Punkt zu veranschaulichen:

Nein, leider nicht. Die Richtlinie über die Stack-Exchange-Netzwerk ist, dass alle Fragen in Englisch mit Ausnahme jener Fälle, in denen eine Seite ist speziell in einer anderen Sprache(zB [Portuguese SO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), [Französisch](https://french.stackexchange.com/) oder [Spanisch](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/)) Jede Website, die nicht explizit sprachspezifische ist implizit bestimmte in Englisch..

Allerdings können Sie einen Service wie verwenden [Google Translate] (http://translate.google.com) zu, Ihre Beiträge zu übersetzen. Normalerweise ist es eine schreckliche Übersetzung aber ausreichend sein für die Menschen, um Ihre Frage zu verstehen. Andere Benutzer können dann bearbeiten, um das Problem zu beheben und die Verbesserung der Übersetzung.

---

<sup>I don't speak German so I have no idea whether the translation even resembles what I wrote.</sup>

Comment: @guntbert I rolled back your edit because, while I am sure you made the translation much better, I included it precisely to give the OP an idea of the level of quality he can expect from google translate. Correcting it defeats the purpose :). Thanks though!